# SQL Server Select query validations

Tags: sql-server, select, case-statement

I have a MS SQL query on which I am using CASE STATEMENT. Like below -

```
SELECT NAME, EMAIL,
CASE Type WHEN LEN(Type) > 1 
           THEN 'LENGHT EXCEED' 
          WHEN '' 
           THEN 'Type is required' 
          WHEN NULL 
           THEN 'Type is required' 
          ELSE '' 
END
FROM TABLE
```

In the above query I am using CASE STATEMENT TO PUT VALIDATION on Type field.
I am applying length and required field validations in the query.

But LEN(Type) > 1 is not working.
 It's

> showing wrong syntax.

Can any one suggest how I can use it and also how we can call a function inside CASE STATEMENT.

Comment: Replace `CASE type WHEN` with `CASE WHEN`

Comment: yes it will work with CASE WHEN but what about other condition (required) validation ? Can you suggest the syntax for both  ?

Comment: come on, you could search for the right syntax: `CASE WHEN LEN([Type]) > 1 THEN 'LENGHT EXCEED' WHEN [Type] = '' THEN 'Type is required' WHEN [Type] IS NULL THEN 'Type is required' ELSE '' END`

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
   CASE WHEN LEN(Type) > 1 
        THEN 'LENGHT EXCEED' 
        WHEN Type = '' 
        THEN 'Type is required' 
        WHEN Type IS NULL 
        THEN 'Type is required' 
        ELSE 
   END
```

Comment: No, it's not gonna work for every condition. You shouldn't use `WHEN type = NULL`, it's `WHEN type IS NULL`